# Take image input and get 3 float outputs with Machine Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, python-3.7

I have an image that consists of only black and white pixels. 500x233px. I want to use this image as an input, or maybe all the pixels in the image as individual inputs, and then receive 3 floating point values as output using machine learning.

I have spent all day on this and have come up with nothing. The best I can find is some image classification libraries, but I am not trying to classify an image. I’m trying to get 3 values that range from -180.0 to 180.0.

I just want to know where to start. Tensorflow seems like it could probably do what I want, but I have no idea where to start with it.

I think my main issue is that I don’t have one output for each input. I’ve been trying to use each pixel’s value (0 or 1) as an input, but my output doesn’t apply to each pixel, only to the image as a whole. I’ve tried creating a string of each pixel’s value and using that as one input, but that didn’t seem to work either.

Should I be using neural networks? Or genetic algorithms? Or something else? Or would I be better off with only receiving one of the three outputs I need, and just training three different models for each output? Even then, I’m not sure how to get a floating point value out of these things. Maybe machine learning isn’t even the correct approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are looking for unsupervised or supervised approach? I mean to say, do you have any "3 float"s in mind for for an image, which you can use as targets to train the network, or do you want something like clustering?

Comment: I have known data that I am wanting to train it on.

Comment: Then it is not that difficult. Start with the array of images as feature, and the known data as target. And start with the simplest form of neural network, that is MLP. Start with one intermediate layer, small number of neurons. See how your training goes, then tweak with your hyperparameters.

Comment: But I don't understand how to send the images as a feature. Do i send an array of all the pixel values? Do I use some kind of image object?

Comment: Yes, all the pixel values. Flatten the thing so that each sample has `500x233 = 116500` features,. so if there are x images, your input feature shape would be `[x, 116500]` and your target shape would be `[x, 3]`